# Fileoutputstream creates file that doesn't inherit Win ACL

Tags: java, windows, acl

I noticed a strange behaviour as follows:

1. I create a folder c:\ProgramData\MyApp
2. ACL to full access for everyone: icacls.exe c:\ProgramData\MyApp /grant:r "*S-1-1-0":(OI)(CI)F
3. Copy a file something.txt to c:\ProgramData\MyApp => File inherits ACL (everyone has full access)
4. I do a new FileWriter(new File(something.txt)), null) or new Fileoutputstream(...) and after that, the file doesn't have this ACL anymore.

System: Windows 7 64 Bit

Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance!
Peter